# Im getting the query for all customers (ID, Email, Name) who have spent above X amount during their entire purchase history

Tags: sql

These are 3 tables that I have and Im getting the query for all customers (ID, Email, Name) who have spent above X amount during their entire purchase history.

```
CREATE TABLE Sales (
    Sales ID int PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    Customer ID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID),
    Product ID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Product(SKU ID),
    Quantity int,
    Date Datetime
);

CREATE TABLE Product (
    SKU ID int PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    Product Name vchar(255),
    Price int,
    Discount Price double,
    In Stock int
);

CREATE TABLE Customer (
    CustomerID int PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    EmailAddress vchar(255),
    FirstName vchar(255),
    LastName vchar(255),
    Gender vchar(255)
);
```

This is the query that I wrote but I still can't get the result that I need .

```
SELECT c.customerid, c.emailaddress, c.firstname
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN sales s ON s.customerid = c.customerid
INNER JOIN product p ON s.productid = p.productid
HAVING SUM(s.quantity * p.price) > Xamount;
```

Comment: Where is your `group by`?

Comment: `GENERATED BY DEFAULT` is not SQL Server syntax, which DBMS are you using, please tag correctly

Comment: By Google-Fu says that the above is PostgreSQL, not SQL Server. Though I can't find *any* documentation on the datatype `vchar` for PostgreSQL. I have, for now, removed the tag [[tag:sql-server]], as it is clearly wrong.

Comment: @Larnu: it's also not Postgres, as that doesn't have a `datetime` data type.

Comment: Yeah, it's why I noted it's my Google-Fy that suggests it, @a_horse_with_no_name , and even then, that that didn't look right because of the `vchar` data type. Unless the OP actually tags the correct RDBMS, I would suggest we don't really know. The fact that it also has straight up syntax issues though (`In Stock int` for example) suggests that they didn't check or try said SQL before they posted it.

Comment: @lamu may I know what is the correct tag for my post to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `GROUP BY` clause

```sql
SELECT c.customerid, c.emailaddress, c.firstname
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN sales s ON s.customerid = c.customerid
INNER JOIN product p ON s.productid = p.productid
GROUP BY c.customerid, c.emailaddress, c.firstname
HAVING SUM(s.quantity * p.price) > @amount;
```

You can also do this with a semi-join, using `EXISTS` or a correlated subquery

```sql
SELECT c.customerid, c.emailaddress, c.firstname
FROM customer c
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM sales s
    INNER JOIN product p ON s.productid = p.productid
    WHERE s.customerid = c.customerid
    HAVING SUM(s.quantity * p.price) > @amount
);
-- alternatively
WHERE (
    SELECT SUM(s.quantity * p.price)
    FROM sales s
    INNER JOIN product p ON s.productid = p.productid
    WHERE s.customerid = c.customerid
) > @amount;
```

In DBMSs that support it, you could also do this with an `APPLY` or `LATERAL JOIN`

```sql
SELECT c.customerid, c.emailaddress, c.firstname
FROM customer c
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT SUM(s.quantity * p.price) AS total
    FROM sales s
    INNER JOIN product p ON s.productid = p.productid
    WHERE s.customerid = c.customerid
    GROUP BY ()
    HAVING SUM(s.quantity * p.price) > @amount
) p;
```

Comment: thank you!! Yes I forget my group by. and I have a script to get a query for Total aggregated sales of customer by gender in the past 3 months and this is my query - select c.gender , sum(s.quantity * p.price) as total sales from customer c inner join sales s on s.customerid = c.customerid inner join product p on s.productid = p.productid WHERE s.Date >= DATEADD(M, -3, GETDATE()) group by c.gender

Is there any other way to write to get this result ?

Comment: Is there something wrong with that method?