# Im getting the query for Total aggregated sales of customer by gender in the past 3 months

Tags: sql

These are 3 tables that I have and Im getting the query for Total aggregated sales of customers by gender in the past 3 months.

```
CREATE TABLE Sales (
    Sales ID int PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    Customer ID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID),
    Product ID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Product(SKU ID),
    Quantity int,
    Date Datetime
);

CREATE TABLE Product (
    SKU ID int PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    Product Name vchar(255),
    Price int,
    Discount Price double,
    In Stock int
);

CREATE TABLE Customer (
    CustomerID int PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    EmailAddress vchar(255),
    FirstName vchar(255),
    LastName vchar(255),
    Gender vchar(255)
);
```

This is the query that I wrote. Is there any way to write this script?

```
select c.gender , sum(s.quantity * p.price) as total sales 
from   customer c 
       inner join sales s on s.customerid = c.customerid 
       inner join product p on s.productid = p.productid 
WHERE  s.Date >= DATEADD(M, -3, GETDATE()) 
group by c.gender
```

Comment: In your query `inner join product p on s.productid = p.productid` I don't see a `productid` in the `Product ` schema

Comment: You never did clarify what RDBMS you are using in your prior question. Neither `vchar` or `double` are valid data types in SQL Server. The syntax `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY` isn't valid T-SQL syntax at all, and you have other syntax errors like `In Stock int` in there. This looks almost like a complete [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69724348/im-getting-the-query-for-all-customers-id-email-name-who-have-spent-above-x) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close, I think that will be the correct query:

```
select 
    c.gender, 
    sum(s.quantity * p.price)
from Sales s
join Product p on s.ProductId = p.SkuId
join Customer c on s.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
group by c.gender
```